# Make a cell stretch across two rows in android

Tags: android, rows, tablelayout, stretch

I've been asked to design a UI for a calculator application in Android using buttons. The GUI needs to be as in the image below-
[image]

The only issue I have is to stretch the '+' cell across two rows, as shown in the picture.
I could simply assign a value to the layout_height to achieve this, but that would give me problems if the app is viewed on a different screen size.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) allows you to [span cells](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) across rows as well as columns, plus, it can be filled Vertically or horizontally. You'd need a 6X5 grid, with different resolution images for different screens.

Comment: Damn! I had tried everything but that. Im a beginner. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

When you add  your "+" button to layout, make sure it occupies 2 rows instead of 1 by setting rowSpan to 2. You can do it in code like

```
layout->addWidget(yourPlusButton,row,column,2/*rowSpan*/,1/*columnSpan*/);
```

If you are using QtCreator, you can achieve this by kind of stretching "+" button with a mouse (I'm assuming you are using QGridLayout for that) - so you stretch it to empty cell below it to make it occupy two cells.